# Is there any method to draw Path (Polyline) on Leaflet with constant width/stroke in meters instead pixels?

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet, polyline

Does anyone known any working method to draw polylines on Leaflet with constant width in meters?

I can't find any working solutions for this. Documentation about Leaflet Path have only stroke with weight in pixels.

Comment: I think you are asking for so called buffers. Try to check e.g. the [`Leaflet.buffer`](https://github.com/skeate/Leaflet.buffer) plugin (haven't tried it personally).

Answer (score 3):

I've just published `leaflet-corridor` plugin which does exactly what you asked for: draws a polyline with width fixed in meters.

[Demo](http://mikhail.io/demos/leaflet-corridor/)

[Github repository](https://github.com/mikhailshilkov/leaflet-corridor)

Usage:

```
var corridor = L.corridor([/*Array of L.latlng*/], widthInMeters);
map.addLayer(corridor);
```

Comment: The demo is not working, as it can't load Leaflet. Can you update the link to Leaflet, please?

Comment: @user502144 Done

Comment: @Mikhail This looks fantastic. I would love to see this integrated into the leaflet package for R

Comment: @Lee88 If that's something you can do, be my guest :) I have no idea about R integration.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any method like that, but knowing the density of pixels on the screen, you can get the number of pixels you need for 1 meter.

Comment: It sounds like good idea but I don't have any idea how to get destiny of pixels on screen - it is also based on map zoom level I think. 

I have also other idea to draw polylines using many leaflet circles with radius in meters. But I think that can be a problem with huge amount of circles on map.

Comment: @user3476099 The best is really to "think in pixel", like your computer will. Can't you merely add a scale to let user know the "real" distance ? 

DPI is very often 96.

Answer (score 0):

Your map tile provider probably provides the meters/pixel data for all the zoom levels. OpenStreetMaps example: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels

Then add an event to zoomend that scales the strokewidth of your polyline(s) based on the current zoom level.